# How to export test results in MSTest using cake script?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am using VS 2017 professional (version 15.2) with platform of Asp.net core (version 1.1). I am using a testing framework of MSTest (which is in the internal template of asp.net core). I try to use the cake script for running the test cases written in MSTest using the cake script, I need to export test results like passed and failed test case count.

```
     MSTest("./Tests/*.UnitTests.dll");
```

When I run this code in cake test execution should be finished but I need detailed test results.

Can anyone please suggest how to export the results of test cases?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation](https://cakebuild.net/dsl/mstest/) for the `MSTest` cake Alias.

2 of the overloads accept a `MSTestSettings` argument, [doc](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.MSTest/MSTestSettings/).

1. `MSTest(ICakeContext, IEnumerable<FilePath>, MSTestSettings)` - Runs all MSTest unit tests in the specified assemblies.
2. `MSTest(ICakeContext, string, MSTestSettings)`- Runs all MSTest unit tests in the assemblies matching the specified pattern.

This argument has a string property `ResultsFile` where you can set the location for the results to be written, [doc](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.MSTest/MSTestSettings/9AA2E01B).